# Logback creating logs at maven run but not when it deployed

Tags: java, logback

Using log-back for logging.When building project with Maven its creating log files and writing logs but not same, when running Spring Runner test case or deployed on server.Its just creating empty log file.

Following is my Configuration,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration  scan="true" scanPeriod="1000000 seconds">

   <appender name="consoleOutput"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>%d{hh:mm:ss} %-5level %c:%M:%L %m%n- %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

     <!-- Appender:  for logging all the Logs into the Log file --> 

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ALL</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
        </filter>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <customFilSystem>true</customFilSystem>
      <!-- rollover daily -->
      <fileNamePattern>log/LOGFILE-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt.zip</fileNamePattern>
      <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
        <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 100MB -->
        <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
        <minIndex>1</minIndex>
        <maxIndex>2</maxIndex>
      </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{hh:mm:ss} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
  </appender>

    <root level="ALL" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="consoleOutput"/>
    </root>

  <!-- Specify the package or module and reference of respective Appender -->

     <logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: For your tests, did you specify a logback-test.xml file?

Comment: You should only ever have *one* root element. Also, the additivity-option does not apply to it.

Comment: Yes,I have the logback-test.xml and tried But still problem is generating logs in maven install but not in deployment.